# How can I make sure no method of an instance is being called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a couple of [small dieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) in my code that cause pains when testing. Assume that breaking the small gods into pieces is too much effort for this exercise.

The usual problem is that I want to test a method `x()` of `Foo` but to create an instance of `Foo`, I need to define N (1 < N < 10) mock instances which are only there to satisfy Spring's `@Autowire`. In production, I must be sure that these fields are wired, so making these optional isn't an option.

Possible solutions I see:

1. Tell Spring somehow that some `@Autowire` fields are optional for the duration of the test
2. Pass in uncallable mocks for anything that the code under test won't/shouldn't need.

Since I don't know a way to do #1, I think #2 is the way to go. What I would prefer is a bean factory which returned a proxy that throws an exception for any method call for any bean which I didn't define.

So for any unknown bean, it should call this `create` method:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class MustNotCallMe {

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public static <T> T create( final Class<T> type, final Class<?>... types ) {
        InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke( Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args ) throws Throwable {

                if( "equals".equals( method.getName() ) && Object.class.equals( method.getDeclaringClass() ) ) {
                    return proxy == args[0];
                }

                throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "You must not call " + method );
            }
        };

        Class<?>[] allClasses = new Class<?>[ types.length + 1 ];
        allClasses[0] = type;
        System.arraycopy( types, 0, allClasses, 1, types.length );

        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance( MustNotCallMe.class.getClassLoader(), allClasses, handler );
    }
}
```

Does something like this exist? If not, how would I inject my own bean factory in a Spring 3 unit test?

**EDIT** I'm aware that this idea upsets any language purist. Only reality is rarely pure. If someone here is willing to step up and give us the money and hands necessary to refactor the software, we'd love to hear about it. Until then, a solution that solves the problem without much manual work solves our specific problem much better :-)

That said, all I need is a way to create a `BeanFactory` which never throws `NoSuchBeanException` but returns a "don't call me" proxy instead.

Comment: Why do you particularly need a bean factory? I would normally expect you to test code *without* using any autowiring - just by passing values into a normal constructor (or setting properties). As such, a normal strict mock (e.g. via Mockito or EasyMock) should be fine.

Comment: Is your spring version 3.0.X? Starting with 3.1.X version spring supports [profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), they might help in your case.

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.2 and Mockito, if that helps.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'd prefer that as well but the code has become too complex and we don't have the manpower to fix it right now, so I'll accept the second best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to the area, but I thought the whole idea of Spring was that it was easy to swap out pieces for testing and other changes in environment.

Looking at it from the viewpoint of someone who (thinks he) understands the concepts but has not implemented anything major in it, what's wrong with this: each autowired piece is an interface.  Imagine a class implementing that interface where every method merely calls an error-reporting mechanism of some sort -- it can be the same one for all of them.  Creating such a class (by hand) should be quick, not error-prone, and now you have your 'mock'.  If you've got 10 of these, it shouldn't take that long to create such a class for every one of them.

Now create a spring configuration file that passes in such ones of these mocks as are necessary for a given set of tests.  If something calls a mock class, it spits out the above error.  Different configurations can include different mocks, of course, for different testing environments.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I could do all that work manually or let a program do it for me. My point is that it's easy to write this code; I just don't know how to fit it into Spring's BeanFactory API.

Answer (score 1):

The golden path is: don't use Spring in your Test, just setup your dependencies with plain vanilla java code. If this is painfull, you have a strong indicator how to refactor your code. That is a good thing. For the dependencies that shall not be called you provide mocks that blow up on every method call. An easy way to achieve this should be this nifty Mockito feature: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#14

The dirty path: If you a stuck in a legacy swamp where you can't bear to setup all the dependencies in a test (and the presence of minor gods is an indicator for that) you can use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` + Spring profiles (if you use Spring 3.1 or higher I think).

With this you can have for example a `prod` profile which you use for your production environment and a `integrationtest` profile which replaces all the beans-that-must-not-be-called with mocks as described above. Google "spring + profiles" for various tutorials. It is easy and works like a charm ... but is only suitable if you have a fixed set of beans that you want to replace. If you have 50 tests, each needing a different subset of 20 beans replaced by blowing-up-on-call-beans, it gets even worse:

The hellish path: Use Spring, but replace a specifc set of beans with blowing-up-on-call-beans on a per test level. You can do that by having special context configuration that contain a configuration for a single bean to be replaced. It must have the same name/id as the production bean, but a blow up on call implementation (again via Mockito if you like). On each test you then use a ContextConfiguration Annotation like the following:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"applicationContext.xml", "blowUpDemiGod42.xml",
    "blowUpDemiGod23.xml"})
```

This will make the configuration in the `blowUpDemiGod*.xml` files overwrite the configuration from your `applicationContext.xml`

There might be a light form of the hellish path, where you can provide the bean in the test via Java code ... not sure.

Comment: I like the Mockito feature because I already use it for other tests ... Mockito just has too many features ;-) But is there really no way to create an "autoconstructor BeanFactory"?